# How to detect RSS Feed changes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rss

I want to add a RSS feed into my WPF app, and I've been following the [C# / WPF: Creating A Simple RSS Reader in 15 Minutes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3y7VNw8ksY) video on YouTube.

It shows how to setup a XmlDataProvider for the RSS feed and display the values in a list box. But one thing it doesn't show is how to automatically update/refresh the list box when the RSS changes.

Can someone please show me how to display the new values when the RSS feed changes?

Comment: There's no push technology behind RSS, it's really simple, right?  You need to create a background poller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`XmlDataProvider` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> XmlDataProvider performs a full refresh of all bindings when a XmlDocument.NodeChanged event occurs.

From the [`XmlDocument.NodeChanged` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.nodechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, this event:

> Occurs when the Value of a node belonging to this document has been changed

Therefore, your `XmlDataProvider` should refresh whenever any `Node` in it is changed.
However, if your `XmlDataProvider` does not refresh when you change the `Source` property value, then you can call the [`DataSourceProvider.Refresh` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.datasourceprovider.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on it in code to manually refresh it:

```
yourXmlDataProvider.Refresh();
```

Comment: I'm binding the XmlDataProvider Source to a webservice URL (and not using a XmlDocument). Unfortunately the XmlDataProvider.DataChanged event doesn't fire when a new post is added to the RSS feed.